# Is there an elegant way to iterate through an array and stop before the end?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I've want to write code that does this (well, a much more complex version of this, anyway):

```
answer = nil
array.each do |e|
  x = complex_stuff_with(e)
  if x.is_the_one_i_want?
    answer = x
    break
  end
end
```

This is obviously not satisfactory.  Iterating through an array like this is a code smell.

Ideally, I want some method on Array that will let me test each element in turn, and return my answer and stop when I have one.  **Is there such a method?**

The closest I've been able to come to it is by using `break` inside `#inject`.  But I'm still basically doing the iteration by hand!

```
answer = array.inject do |_,e|
  x = complex_stuff_with(e)
  break x if x.is_the_one_i_want?
end
```

**Update**: It would appear that the reason I can't find such a method is because no such method exists.

**Update**: Spoke too soon!  I need the Lazy Operator! Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Maybe you could create a method and use `return x if x.is_the_one_i_want?` inside the loop. I do not know why exactly you need that and the limitations you are facing, but I don't think that would be bad

Comment: @LucasWieloch ...aaand, that's my _first_ example.  Except that `return` is wrong, that would leave the method not the block.  You need `break`.

Comment: `answer = find_element_x(array)` and `def find_element_x(array) ... end` would leave the method returning to where you want your answer

Comment: This has been something of a waste of time for everyone involved.  I can't delete the question and none of the reasons for marking it closed seem correct.  Apologies to anyone who spent time reading this...

Comment: I have to disagree.  Both you and @LucasWieloch have solutions that work, you just seem to be rejecting them based on some personal aesthetic.  That makes this closable as a matter of opinion, which is why I voted to do so.

Comment: @pjs -- If you hover over the "idioms" tag, you will see "a preferred way to write code, when there is more than one way to do so".  I was pretty clear about what I was looking for.  I now have two answers that fit that, and I've ticked one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are effectively doing is, first [`map`ping](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) the elements of the `Array` with a transformation, and then [`find`ing](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) the *first* transformed element that satisfies some predicate.

We can express this like this (I'm re-using the definitions from [@iGian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57824325/2988), but with an added side-effect so that you can observe the evaluation of the transformation operation):

```
def complex_stuff_with(e)
  p "#{__callee__}(#{e.inspect})"
  e**2
end

ary = [1, 2, 3, 2]
x_i_want = 4

ary
  .map(&method(:complex_stuff_with))
  .find(&x_i_want.method(:==))
# "complex_stuff_with(1)"
# "complex_stuff_with(2)"
# "complex_stuff_with(3)"
# "complex_stuff_with(2)"
#=> 4
```

This gives us the correct result but not the correct side-effects. You want the operation to be [`lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy). Well, that's easy, we just need to convert the [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) to a [*lazy enumerator*](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html) first:

```
ary
  .lazy
  .map(&method(:complex_stuff_with))
  .find(&x_i_want.method(:==))
# "complex_stuff_with(1)"
# "complex_stuff_with(2)"
#=> 4
```

Or, using the definitions from your question:

```
array
  .lazy
  .map(&method(:complex_stuff_with))
  .find(&:is_the_one_i_want?)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
answer = array.find do |e|
  x = complex_stuff_with(e)
  break x if x.is_the_one_i_want?
end
```

I took this code from [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/35569-how-to-iterate-over-an-enumerable-returning-the-first-truthy-result-of-a-block-map-find)

Comment: Sorry, that's not right.  `find` will return `e` if the exit value (`x` in this case) is truthy.  I want the method to return `x`.  Also, it's exactly the same as my second example in my question, with the method changed from `inject` to `find`? :/

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't remember of inject method in ruby. I thought that could be just an example of what you wanted and it occurred to me that this method could be the one.

Comment: @AndyJones This works as intended because of the `break`. With that, the method will return the argument to `break` (that is: `x`) instead of the usual return value of `find`. If no value is the one, the method will return as usual and the find will return `nil`. Note here the difference between `next` (which will return the given value from the currently invoked block) and `break` (which will immediately return the given value from the method which invoked the current block, i.e. `find` in this case).

Comment: @HolgerJust -- okay, it works, but it's actually worse than my own example in that you expect `#find` to return an element from the array.  This behaviour doesn't appear to be well documented. At least with `#inject` it's clear that the resulting answer to the block will be calculated inside the block.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Lazy Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html)!

```
array.lazy.map {|e| expensive_stuff(e) }.detect(&:is_the_one_i_want?)
```

This makes Ruby evaluate the whole chain of operations (map, detect) for each element one at a time, rather than evaluating the map for all elements, then the detect, etc. This lets you do complex and expensive stuff in the map without having to compute it over the whole enumerable.

To illustrate:

```
expensive_stuff = ->(x) { puts "Doing expensive stuff with #{x}" ; x }
result = (1..Float::INFINITY).lazy.map {|e| expensive_stuff[e] }.detect(&:even?)
puts "Result: #{result}"

# Doing expensive stuff with 1
# Doing expensive stuff with 2
# Result: 2
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's brilliant!  And a very clear explanation.  I'm going to give the tick to Jorg, though, since he got there first.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Not a problem! I just skimmed the answers and missed that he'd talked about lazy - he deserves it :)

Answer (score 0):

Other couple of option, only if for your code is viable the following simplification:

```
def complex_stuff_with(e)
  e**2
end

ary = [1, 2, 3, 2] # integer objects
x_i_want = 4 # instead of x.is_the_one_i_want?
```

So, in that case:

```
res = ary.find { |e| complex_stuff_with(e) == x_i_want}.then { |e| e ? x_i_want : :whatever }
#=> 4
```

or using [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
res = x_i_want if ary.any? { |e| complex_stuff_with(e) == x_i_want }
#=> 4
```

In both cases the iteration exits as soon as the first element matches the condition.